# Error when upload .zip file to Amazon S3 from AWS farget container. but Locally its working as expected

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

In application making .zip and uploaded back to s3 then got below error. I tried with below code.

```
consts3=newAWS.S3({​​​
    accessKeyId:config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey:config.AWS_SK,
    region:config.AWS_REGION,
    apiVersion:'2006-03-01',
    signatureVersion:'v4',
    params:{​​​Bucket:config.AWS_BUCKET}​​​
}​​​);

  s3.upload(params, (s3Err, data) => {​​​
   if (s3Err) throw s3Err;if (data) {
    ​​​console.log("File uploaded successfully at location​​​");
    fs.rmdir(folderName + ".zip", {​​​recursive: true}​​​, 
    async (err) => {​​​
    if (err) {​​​throw err;}​​​
     console.log("File is deleted!");
  }​​​)
```

-----------------------Got below error from cloud watch log----------------

@ingestionTime
1633704322710

@log
XXXX:/ecs/XXX-ar-XXX-api-service

@logStream
XXXX-ar-XXXXapi-service-log/XXX-ar-XXX-api-service/feXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

@message
Zip created successfully
BRANCH__1000__20211008-021020 is deleted!

**Exception origin: uncaughtExceptionCaught exception:
AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".**

@timestamp
1633703958610

Comment: Why are you specifying the apiVersion, the region, the signatureVersion etc.!?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is just creating the `s3` instance which you're using for the upload. The error that you're getting is probably triggered from the line in your code where you're calling `s3.upload(...` Please post the relevant code and the full error including stacktrace if possible.